# What options are being used by sed to parse a file and write to new file

Tags: shell-script, sed

I am debugging a LINUX script that was written by someone else.  In the script we have a line of code like below

```
sed -i "\#</resources>#{h;s#.*#cat /opt/abc/new.xml#e;G}" /opt/abc/tempmodule.xml
```

It seems it is doing some pattern matching and substitute and then copying the content from new.xml to tempmodule.xml.  But what is the meaning of those options used within sed? Can this be explained.

My understanding so far is

it  is trying to find a text "`</resources>`" in tempmodule.xml and replace the content with new.xml

I do not know what `#` means in this line.  But when I check the sed manual it says commented line.. but I dont think here it means different.

Comment: What is your research effort? Have you tried reading the manual of your `sed`? What relevant facts have you learned? What parts of the command do you think you can explain so far? and what your partial explanation is (even if it may be wrong)? The author chose to use `#` instead of commonly used `/`. The code in the "traditional" form with slashes would be `sed -i "/…/ {h;s/…/…/e;G}" pathname`; what parts are familiar to you?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for your comment.  I have updated the question with some of my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script

```
sed -i "\#</resources>#{h;s#.*#cat /opt/abc/new.xml#e;G}" /opt/abc/tempmodule.xml
```

can also be written like this, thus comments can be added:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -i -f

                     # As separator "#" is used. Using "\#" prevents the
                     # line being interpreted as a comment.

\#</resources>#{     # search the string "</resources>". if found execute:

    h                # store a copy of the buffer in the hold space.

    s#.*#cat /opt/abc/new.xml#e  
                     # substitute the whole line by "cat /opt/abc/new.xml"
                     # and "e" execute it in a shell. The new content of 
                     # the line is the content of "/opt/abc/new.xml".
                     # This might be multiple lines now.

    G                # To the changed content of the buffer append the 
                     # content of the hold space (the originally read line
                     # with the string "</resources>") as a new line at the
                     # end of the buffer.
}
```

The file `/opt/abc/tempmodule.xml` is the input file.
The option `-i` defines that the output shall go to the input file and replace it "inplace" — At the end the input file contains the new content.

Line by line the inputfile is read to sed's buffer. Independent of being changed or not, at the end of the commands the buffer will be sent to the output and the cycle restarts by reading a new line to the buffer.

*The script changes the file `/opt/abc/tempmodule.xml` by inserting the content of `/opt/abc/new.xml` just before the (every) line containing `</resources>` thus appending items to the end of the xml-object "resources".*

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answers in the very complete and readable GNU sed [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command), especially the `s` command, where it says:

> The syntax of the s command is ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’.
>
> The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given `s` command.

> The `s` command can be followed by zero or more of the following flags:
>
> `e` This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern
> space...

Further on we [have](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses):

> 4.3 selecting lines by text matching
>
> \%regexp%
>
> (The % may be replaced by any other single character.)
> This also matches the regular expression regexp, but allows one to use a
> different delimiter than /.